# Phonegap App: Store all data in one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, cordova, size

I currently developing an App with phonegap and jquerymobile.
The App contains a lot of data which will be displayed to the user. All the Data is stored in with the phonegap storage implementation.
The data will be visible to the user in listviews, detailviews and filtered listviews and so on - no problem so far, but here comes my question:

Because of the asynchronous way of the phonegap storage methodes (which lead to problems with relational data) and the fact that much of the data is (at least partial) used in all views i´m thinking about storing all the Data in one big javascript object, so all the data is loaded on startup and there would be no need for many db actions.

I think the object would contain around 10 2-4 dimensional hash-arrays with together max. 2000-3000 entries.

Is this possible or will this slow the app down too much. 
Is there another approach i could or should use.

---

answer to erik:

but i recognized that i should have explained things a bit more:

The data which will be in the object consists of one 3 arrays with many enitiys like entity{name, headline, subheadline, description, creation date, update date, small string, small string, small string}, all other arrays contain mostly relation identifiers for the 3 bigger arrays.

none of these arrays would be changed or manipulated - the only thing that could happen is a complete change for all the data because of a syncronisation with a server.

also important could be, that all of the data is stored local, and because the app is realised with jquery mobile, so there will be no reloading of the page - if other content should be displayed, required html is loaded javascript and inserted in the page.

still no good idea? if yes, no good idea - what would be a better approach?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might slow the app down on load, just for the fact that it needs to allocate so much space for the object. From there, it won't be any slower/faster, but depending on how you're using the object, when accessing/manipulating the object, think of how hard/involved it will be to use items in the object. It may be easy, but for example, if you have to iterate over thousands of items because you need to "find" one, it may be intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "entries" I guess, but it sounds to me like potential for a massive load burden followed by a very large object needlessly in memory. First I would recommend expressing the object as a string somewhere. The number of characters in that thing represents the number of bytes you're actually loading per-page since I'm assuming it won't be in the form of a one-time load js file that never changes and the browser has to parse the silly thing after the page loads.

My instincts say this is the wrong way to go regardless. If you have a need for beyond 2D arrays, this thing sounds like it could go well into the megabytes which is going to add whole seconds to load time, but more importantly, it sounds like you're trying to do something which only partially mitigates your real problems, if anything, since this only helps you with reduction of initial look-ups but not updating, which is where async on the client-side can get really messy. Also, if there's potential for growth in that data, what seems manageable now, could very easily ruin your app in the future.

The key to avoiding excess HTTP requests is to always have static data baked into the page as well as first-tier stuff if it's economical (e.g. the stuff in the first select box that you click on to load stuff in the dependent select box). And cache the results of ajax calls wherever possible.

The key thing in the client-side logic is to have a consistent, manageable API to grab server-side data with and to never represent anything as changed or finished until the server confirms that it's in fact, happened.

Comment: Hey Erik, thanks for your answer - please look at my question, there is a formated replay.